# Unknown action hashit in contract eosio

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosjs, eosio-code, eosio.token

> stdClass Object ( [code] => 500 [message] => Internal Service Error [error] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 3050000 [name] => action_validate_exception [what] => Action validate exception [details] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Unknown action hashit in contract eosio [file] => chain_plugin.cpp [line_number] => 1831 [method] => abi_json_to_bin ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [message] => code: eosio, action: hashit, args: ["boxwork1","boxwork2","0.0001 EOS","Testy McTest"] [file] => chain_plugin.cpp [line_number] => 1842 [method] => abi_json_to_bin ) ) ) )

Can I create custom action using cleos?

Comment: Your question title and the content of the question are quite different. The account `eosio` does not contain the transfer operation. You likely mean to use `eosio.token` account. Please make your question more clear for more assistance.

Comment: my fault, I was trying to push a custom action there called "Hash".
And the issue I am facing is Unknown action hash in contract eosio. But I go the solution just going to put it below. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I was trying to push a custom action called "hashit". So for hashit action, I have created a hash.cpp file

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
using namespace eosio;
class hash : public contract {
public:
  using contract::contract;
  [[eosio::action]]
  void hashit( name user ) {
     print( "Hello, ", name{user} );
  }
};
```

and I have generated wasm and abi file with cmd `eosio-cpp -o hash.wasm hash.cpp -abigen`

and then set contract with cleos. And **it works**.